# Is there a way to make the Atom or Sublime text editor have striped lines?

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

I would like the text editor to have alternating colors, like white on even numbered lines, and gray on odd numbered lines, the way a striped table looks. Is there a way to do that? Thank you!

Comment: In Sublime, the color of text (and the background color) is controlled by the color scheme, and the color scheme applies colors based on the rules in the syntax. So this is only possible if you have a syntax definition that does something to alternate the scope of every second line. Something like that would almost certainly not be able to do any sort of syntax highlighting other than the background colors of alternate rows.

Comment: You're asking for us to find or recommend off-site packages. That's off-topic. Instead, you should do the research, locate, and try things, select one, then, when you run into a problem using it ask a specific question about that particular thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple google search my friend: https://atom.io/packages/zebra-stripes

Comment: Thank you. I did google, but for some reason I didn't find this.